# Appveyor clone a private repo

Tags: appveyor

How to use Appveyor to clone a private repo?

For example, I am in the repo A, I need to clone Repo B. 
I don't want to send my personal access token, instead I wanted to send secure token. I tried using appveyor encrypt data tool, and clone the repo. But no luck.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appveyor documentation can get you the key. I understand that the key is tied with your account. If you use your account to encrypt the key and run appveyor (using another account), then it will not work. So you have to use the same account for encryption and decryption.